# Svelte writable store synced to Firebase Realtime DB

Tags: javascript, firebase, svelte, sveltekit

My goal is to create the following:

```html
// my-component.svelte
<script>
    import { project } from '$lib/firebase'
</script>


{#if $project}
    <p>{$project.name}</p>
    <input type="text" bind:value={$project.name}>
{/if}
```

Currently I have the following factory function, which creates a store pointing to a specified realtime DB path:

```js
// $lib/firebase.ts
export function projectStore<Project>(path: string) {
  let unsubscribe: () => void

  const projectRef = ref(realtimeDB, path)

  const { subscribe } = writable<Project | null>(null, (set) => {
    unsubscribe = onValue(projectRef, (snapshot) => {
      set((snapshot.val() as Project) ?? null)
    })

    return () => unsubscribe()
  })

  return {
    subscribe,
    set: (value: any) => {
      return set(projectRef, value)
    },
    update: () => {},
  }
}
```

I also have the following:

```js
// $lib/firebase.ts
export const project: Readable<Project | null> = derived([page, userCredentials], ([$page, $userCredentials], set) => {
  if ($page.params.projectId && $userCredentials) {
    return projectStore<Project>($page.params.projectId).subscribe(set)
  } else {
    set(null)
  }
})
```

This function uses the `projectStore` factory to create a store and exports it. The problem is that if I try to import the `project` derived store it's a Readable store and as soon as I start typing in the input I get errors about `set` being undefined.

The idea behind using a derived store is that I need both an authenticated user and a page with `projectId` in its params.

I can just import the `projectStore` factory in every component and create a store like this:

```js
import { projectStore, userCredentials } from '$lib/firebase'

let _project: any
userCredentials.subscribe((user) => {
  if (user) {
    _project = projectStore($page.params.projectId)
  }
})
```

But it feels wrong, I think I should be able to have a store in a single location and import it anywhere, instead of having a separate store from every component. With the second snipped the two-way binding works, I don't get any errors when I try the example from the start of this question.

How can I make the derived store return the `set` function too?

Answer (score 0):

You were not updating the Svelte store except for when snapshots (`onValue`) arrived.

```
// I assume these are your imports 
import { onValue, ref, set } from "firebase/database"; 
import { writable, get, type Writable } from "svelte/store";

export function projectStore<Project>(path: string): Writable<Project | null> {
  const projectRef = ref(realtimeDB, path)

  const store = writable<Project | null>(null, (setStore) => {
    const unsubscribe = onValue(projectRef, (snapshot: any) => {
      setStore((snapshot.val() as Project) ?? null)
    })

    return unsubscribe;
  })
  
  const setAndStore = (value: any) => {
       set(projectRef, value);
       store.set(value)
  }

  return {
    subscribe: store.subscribe,
    set: setAndStore,
    update: (f) => {
        setAndStore(f(get(store)))
    }
  }
}

// Single universal store (if everyone had the same project, which they do not)
export const project0 = projectStore("0")
```

I assume users have different projects (with different paths), so you would want to use the context API to make each project available to all components. See [this part](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/state-management#using-stores-with-context) of the svelte docs for great instructions on how to use it (and why).

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The projectStore factory is working fine. If I manually create a store with a hardcoded project ID the data binding with firebase works both ways. I can't get the derived store to return a writable store that I can use. When I import { project } from 'firebase.ts' I get only { subscribe} and no set function.